# How to ignore file/folder in SmartGit

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm using SmartGit.
I want to ignore a folder in repository.
When I right-click folder, option "Ignore" is grayed out and I can't click it.

Comment: Same as you always ignore a folder add the <folder-name> into .gitignore file. Then commit the changed file.

Comment: The Ignore can be grayed out if the file is (accidentally) already being tracked

Answer (score 7):

You would need to make sure this folder content isn't versioned first.

In command line, try a `git rm --cached -r yourFolder/`

Then check if the ignore option is now available.

The other reason would be because that folder is empty. since Git doesn't track empty folder, maybe SmartGit doesn't allow to ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Open: Local => "Edit Ignore File..." => "Exclude File" => Edit
Add directory name at new line. For example ".metadata"
=> Save
Done :)

Answer (score 1):

option 1: Right click on the file to ignore -> ignore

option 2: enter the .git / info folder and modify the exclude file.